# Unable to search the records using keyword but the keyword is exists in table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have city table with structure as -

```
#   Name         Type           Collation
1   cityId       int(11)            
2   countryCode  char(5)        latin1_swedish_ci
3   cityName     varchar(100)   utf8mb4_unicode_ci
4   lat          varchar(20)    latin1_swedish_ci
5   lng          varchar(20)    latin1_swedish_ci
```

I have cities for 'countryCode' - 'ad' like -

```
cityId countryCode cityName   lat        lng
1      ad          Aixàs      42.4833333 1.4666667
2      ad          Aixirivali 42.4666667 1.5
3      ad          Aixirivall 42.4666667 1.5
4      ad          Aixirvall  42.4666667 1.5
5      ad          Aixovall   42.4666667 1.4833333
```

But when i execute a query - `SELECT * FROM city WHERE countryCode = 'ad'`, I get empty data. I imported this data from excel sheet having almost 32,00,000 records.
I have checked that there is no space before or after the country code.
Is there any issue with the collation ? Do i need to do some some conversion ? Please help.

Comment: Can you try to use like: `SELECT * FROM city WHERE countryCode like '%ad%`'?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM city WHERE countryCode LIKE '%ad'` ... if this returns those records, then you have a whitespace or similar problem from the Excel import.

Comment: I tried both the queries already, but still result is empty.

Comment: One thing i noticed that when i update the countryCode manually and then search, it returns me those rows for which i updated the countryCode.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT LENGTH(countryCode) WHERE cityId=xx;    (use as xx the id of one your not updated records where  countryCode should be 'ad') (I suppose that if like '%ad% doesn't work there is something invisible between a and d)

Comment: @etsa I'm getting LENGTH(countryCode) as 2 for which i updated, but getting LENGTH(countryCode) as 5 for which i did not updated.

Comment: So now you have something you can use to find the answer... You can try to see what is in using SUBSTRING and ASCII functions

Answer (score 0):

Try collate the text You are searching like that:

```
  SELECT * FROM city WHERE countryCode = 'ad' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: My table collation is 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', so its giving me error as "COLLATION 'latin1_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'"